# Is there a way to change the way Google Sheets Query Group sorts? By both capitals and letter case?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a simple query function that returns a range of names and sums,  grouped by the names.

```
=QUERY('Mamut inklipp'!C:R;"select F, sum(R) group by F";0)
```

This sorts by the names, but case sensitive. A-Z all comes before a-z. Therefore "Eve" comes before "adam". To me that is just plain wrong.

Is there a way to change the the sorting method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to work around that. Pre-processing the data ('before the query') might be an option. Here's a little example.

I hope that works for you?

Note: Depending on your locale, you may have to use commas instead of semi-colons as argument separators (in the formula).

[image: Example]